# Matching across 3 columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What I would like to achieve ideally with a formula is to check the product of 3 columns exists and return a field correlating to the matched product.

An example would look like this - 
[image: example table]

Where the match occurs on col1&col2&col3 and returns the field in col4.  The formula column is ideally what i'd like to return for each match.

I've tried using MATCH and some INDEX searches but neither seem to work

```
=MATCH(A2&B2&C2,A:A&B:B&C:C,0)
```

and

```
=INDEX(D2:D7, MATCH(A2&B2&C2,A:A&B:B&C:C,0))
```

The ideal outcome would be whats shown in the image under the formula column

Comment: I'm not sure your screenshot makes sense. The combination is the same: 1, 2, 3 for both Sam and Susan? Also, assuming the combinations are different, why does the combination for Sam return Susan and vice versa? Shouldn't Sam and Sam, and Susan and Susan, be on the same rows respectively?

Comment: If if's an option, you could create a helper column concatenating the values of col1, col2, and col3, and use that helper column as your lookup array within the MATCH. An easy solution, if acceptable. Also doable without a helper column, if that's needed.